# Error when trying to swap content in 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am working on two sites that have identical bases for all of my 2sxc data/views. I built the first site with no issues, added all my data and was able to add a demo item and then change it to be a data item that already existed in the system.

When I started on my 2nd site, I recreated all the data types and views and started adding content. Adding, deleting and rearranging seems to work fine. But when I try to add a demo item to change it to an existing item, it won't let me change it. I get this error in a popup.

"Had an error talking to the server (status 400)."

So I went back to my first site and now it's doing the same thing. I can't think of anything that would have changed on the first site as far as setup goes. I'm sure I've added more data items since then but I haven't done anything with the data types or view settings.

In each individual module that I've tested, I can still add, delete and move items fine. Just can't swap it for an existing item. Any ideas? I've tried clearing the site cache, restarting the site and reapplying permissions on the entire site as well.

I am running DNN 8.0.4 and 2sxc 9.14.0.

---

I've enabled the extensive logging and this is what I get...

1) When I click on the Replace button:

2sxc-Api:/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/contentgroup/replace?appId=2&guid=9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8&index=1&part=content

ModuleId:2766

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37):parent#2766, content-block#2766, z#2, a#2

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37):real app, will load data

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab):prep App z#2, a#2, allowSE:True, P:0

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)Sxc.Instnc(ef):get SxcInstance for a:2 cb:2766

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)Sxc.Instnc(ef)DNN.Enviro(ef)DN:checking requirements first time for mod:2766

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)Sxc.Instnc(ef)DNN.Enviro(ef)DN:decision: DraftOptional

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab):init data drafts:True, vers:False, hasConf:True

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab)CG.Manage(04):find content-group for mid#2766 and tab#123

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab)CG.Manage(04):get CG or gen preview for grp#9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8, preview#00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab)CG.Manage(04):get CG#9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)DS.Create(cb):will create view data source

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)DS.Create(cb):mid#2766, draft:True, template:Staff-Specialty

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)DS.Factry(37):get init #2/2, draft:True, config:True

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)DS.Create(cb):use pipeline upstream:True

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)DS.Create(cb):override template, & pipe#

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab):init data drafts:True, vers:False, hasConf:True

2sCoGr(65):replace target:9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8, part:content, index:1

2sCoGr(65):get group:9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab)CG.Manage(04):get CG#9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab):configure on demand start

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab)DS.Factry(a8):get init #2/2, draft:True, config:True

2sCoGr(65)CB.Mod(37)App.2sxcAp(ab):configure on demand completed

Server Name: Cloud23294

---

2) When I select an item to replace and click the checkbox button, nothing shows up in the logs - just this popup:

Had an error talking to the server (status 400).

If you are an advanced user...

---

3) When I close out of the Replace Content popup:

2sxc-Api:/DesktopModules/2sxc/API/view/module/rendertemplate?templateId=-1&lang=en-us&cbisentity=false&cbid=2766&originalparameters=%5B%7B%22Key%22%3A%22TabId%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22123%22%7D%2C%7B%22Key%22%3A%22language%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22en-US%22%7D%5D

ModuleId:2766

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a):parent#2766, content-block#2766, z#2, a#2

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a):real app, will load data

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc):prep App z#2, a#2, allowSE:True, P:0

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7):get SxcInstance for a:2 cb:2766

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)DNN.Enviro(da)DN:checking requirements first time for mod:2766

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)DNN.Enviro(da)DN:decision: DraftOptional

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc):init data drafts:True, vers:False, hasConf:True

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc)CG.Manage(32):find content-group for mid#2766 and tab#123

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc)CG.Manage(32):get CG or gen preview for grp#9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8, preview#00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc)CG.Manage(32):get CG#9b9f6f01-063a-481d-a3c7-f2c5923a1fc8

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Create(47):will create view data source

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Create(47):mid#2766, draft:True, template:Staff-Specialty

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Factry(a0):get init #2/2, draft:True, config:True

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Create(47):use pipeline upstream:True

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Create(47):override template, & pipe#

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc):init data drafts:True, vers:False, hasConf:True

2sModC(f9):render template:-1, lang:en-us, isEnt:False

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7):render

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7):system is ready, no upgrade-message to show

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7):pre-init innerContent content is empty so no errors, will build

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7):standard case, found template, will render

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)Htm.RendEn(c7)Ap:init for itm:5885c784-77b3-4c0d-a774-7601101b690b (947)

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)App.2sxcAp(dc):init data drafts:True, vers:False, hasConf:True

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)Htm.RendEn(c7):will render razor template

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)Htm.RendEn(c7):will render into textwriter

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)Sxc.AppHlp(e4):try to build List and Content objects

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Module(19):need content-group, will use from sxc-context

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Module(19):get stream content⋮2, demo#894, present⋮2, presDemo#, header:False

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Publsh(45):get incl. draft:True

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)DS.Module(19):stream:content - items⋮2

2sModC(f9)CB.Mod(2a)Sxc.Instnc(d7)DN.Render(3e)Sxc:building entire client-context

Server Name: Cloud23294

Comment: Try to add more details - incl. what the extensive logging gives you - see https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/releasing-2sxc-9-6-with-extensive-logging

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that was possible. I'll update the question with those logs.

Comment: FYI... I also upgraded to 9.14.0.

Comment: thanks for the logs, but they look completely fine. no idea what it could be :(

Comment: So... what might the next steps be? This is kind of an important feature for them. Do we have to move to paid support? Start from scratch and a fresh install?

Comment: I think your best move is to get an hour or so of paid support on 2sxc.org

Comment: Thank you! I've just submitted the form on the site's contact page.

Comment: Also, just a heads up... out of curiosity, I decided to test another site where I know it was working at one point. That site is now giving the same popup error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Test it with the new version 2sxc 9.13. The error from 9.12 is fixed.

Comment: I upgraded to 9.13 and don't see the issues from 9.12. But I'm still seeing the same issue when I try to swap a demo item for an existing item - still just the "Had an error talking to the server (status 400)." message.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a deeper analysis, it seems that a client security software called WebRoot was interfering. So problem solved :).